# How to plot the resultant vector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a project with vectors but now I want to calculate and plot the resultant vector of vectors that have greater value, for example, between the red and the blue one. This is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations
from numpy import sin, cos
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Circle, PathPatch
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("auto")
ax.set_autoscale_on(True)


#dibujar cubo
r = [-1, 1]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="b")

#dibujar punto
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="g",s=100)

#dibujar vector
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)
print "ingrese coordenada inicial"
#m=float(raw_input())
a = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,1],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k")
b = Arrow3D([0,-1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
c = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="b")
d = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,-1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="g")
e = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="c")
f = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,-0.5],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="m")

ax.add_artist(a)
ax.add_artist(b)
ax.add_artist(c)
ax.add_artist(d)
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.add_artist(f)
plt.show()
```

Any help about doing that?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What _exactly_ are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have to plot the resultant between arrows 'b' and 'c'.

Comment: ok, so what is the problem with your code?

Comment: That I have plot the vectors but I don't know how to plot the resultant between them! Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Your question *contains the answer* as you have a class that will draw arrows between arbitrary points in 3-space

```
 from itertools import cycle
 a = [0, 0, 1]
 b = [1, 0, 1]
 orig = [0, 0, 0]
 for (_b, _e), _c in zip([[orig, a], [orig, b], [a, b]], cycle(['m', 'r', 'g', 'b'])):
     xs, ys, zs = zip(_b, _e)
     res = Arrow3D(xs, ys, zs, mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color=_c)
     ax.add_artist(res)
```

Comment: That's great! But why it change the colors of the arrows, so I was trying to plot the resultant in yellow but I couldn't! :S

Comment: @DiegoMartínezGiardini This makes little sense to me.

Comment: If I change the value of the vector "e", then the resultant doesn't change by itsef, it keeps the same value, so how can I do it automatically?

Comment: I still do not understand.